# Javascript function not working properly in mongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

I have saved regular expressions as a value in collection. I want to check a string against that regular expression in mongodb, whether it Is matching or not? I got to know that I should use javascript code for the same but it’s not working from php-mongodb.

It’s working from mongodb client console.

Here My code,

```
<?php

    $dbName = "XYZ";
    try
    {
            $dbInstanceName = $dbName;
            $mongoInstance  = new Mongo("localhost:27017", array("persist"    => "x"));
            $dbReference = $mongoInstance->$dbInstanceName;
            $db          = $mongoInstance->$dbInstanceName;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e);
            echo "</pre>";
            exit;
    }

    $query  = new MongoCode("function (){return RegExp(this.regCountry).test('India');}");

    $c = "Countries1";

    $cursor = $db->$c->find($query);


    if ($cursor->count() == 0)
    {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r("No Data Found.!");
            echo "</pre>";
            exit;
    }
    else
    {

            $data = array();
            while ($cursor->hasNext())
            {
                    $cursor->next();
                    array_push($data, $cursor->current());
            }                
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
```

?>

its working but return nothing....!

resonse :

```
Array
(

)
```

here, consoled screen sort, its given return a value.

[image]

here my data sample :

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: Thanks for response... i tried but this doesn't matter...

Comment: Try `$c = "Countries1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got Answer :

change my code shown in below

```
<?php

    $dbName = "Scrubly";
    try
    {
            $dbInstanceName = $dbName;
            $mongoInstance  = new Mongo("localhost:27017", array("persist"    => "x"));
            $dbReference = $mongoInstance->$dbInstanceName;
            $db          = $mongoInstance->$dbInstanceName;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e);
            echo "</pre>";
            exit;
    }

    $query = "function(){return db.Countries1.find(function (){return RegExp(this.regCountry).test('India');}).toArray();}";

    $result = $db->execute($query);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;

?>
```

output :

```
Array
(
[retval] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [_id] => MongoId Object
                    (
                        [$id] => 500e5b456bcb44780d000072
                    )

                [country] => India
                [countryCode] => IN
                [createdAt] => 2012-07-24 13:52:29
                [id] => 386
                [regCountry] => ^(.*)India(.*)$
                [updatedAt] => 2012-07-24 13:52:29
            )

    )

[ok] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If my comment above doesn't work, try changing this:

```
$cursor = $db->$c->find($query);
```

to:

```
$cursor = $db->selectCollection($c)->find($query);
```